# Labels with hyperlinks stacked

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, label

I am trying to add some hyperlinks to my label. I would like each hyperlink to be on a new line however I am having trouble getting them to show up one over the other. Everytime I try to add a hyperlink it just appears next to the label instead of underneath it. How do I get it so that it is stacked one over the other?

Below is the code I have now and what is looks like.

[image: what it looks like now]

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManagerComment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <input value="Meeting Scheduled" class="btn btn-link" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("MeetingSch", "Strategy", new {id = Model.StrategyId})'" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ManagerComment, 100, 50, new { id = "questionInput", maxlength = 1000, style = "width: 100%; max-width: 100%" })
            <div id="charsLeft"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <p style="white-space: pre-line">
                    <input value="New Update" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Update", "Strategy", new {id = Model.StrategyId})'" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And below is what I want it to look like:
[image]

Comment: how do you add links in your code? I don't see a c# foreach or js code

Comment: I have an action link "Meeting Schedule which will call a method in the controller. I only did one link for now just to try to get it in the right placement.

Comment: I changed my actionlink code to an input tag

Comment: It should work with links if you wrap them into a div. The problem with links is they are in-line and you need block elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Bootstrap you can add one row per link in that column. Your question doesn't show how you generate links but in terms of styles you can do something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManagerComment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        </div>
        <!--iterate to render links like this-->
        <div class="row">
            @Html.ActionLink("Meeting Scheuduled", "MeetingSch", "Strategy", new { id = Model.StrategyId, @class="col-md-12" })
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            @Html.ActionLink("Meeting Scheuduled 2", "MeetingSch", "Strategy", new { id = Model.StrategyId, @class = "col-md-12" })
        </div>
        <!--end-->
    </div>
</div>
```

By default links are in-line elements that flow with the text on that page. In order to stack those links you can add line breaks. Otherwise use block elements as a container for the links, like I did in the above code sample.

Comment: after doing this with some changes in my divs this works! Thank you

Comment: This did move the link to be formatted the way I'd like but now all my links are overlapping each other even though I assigned a row class to each div.

Comment: No need to create new question, just update the original and uncheck my answer as solution. I don't see overlapped links when I test that code but perhaps there are other styles involved in your case. However I see all links are given same id. This might be an issue though not necessary related to overlapping.

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you so much